# How $regex works in mongoose with empty value

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `$regex` in mongoose, a however a bit confused with its behavior.

Here's my data, I have one document which has one attribute "owner" as below.

```js
{ "owner" : "lorem ipsum" }
```

now when I do search with `{owner: {$regex:"",$options:"i"}}` in MongoDB compass it returns that object, and when I do `{owner: ""}`, it returns nothing.

So can somebody explain to me why this behavior is like this, I do not have an empty string as an owner though while doing `$regex` it returns that  document.

Even I tried to remove space between lorem and "epsum" as "loremepsum" but it had the same behavior. Shouldn't it return same as `{owner: ""}` ?

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus certainly, you and Sarkar suggesting the same thing. Additionally, you depicted with an example, so even I'm not sure about the answer, but this seems logical. Good work to you both and good example MonkeyZeus, certainly it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Mongoose expert by any means but it sounds like it's behaving correctly.

Basically, regexing for `""` results in a compiled regex that looks like `//` which loosely translates to "find me nothing". This "nothing" exists anywhere that something does not exist so "nothing" exists between chars such as `l` and `o` of `lorem`.

This can be best visualized using this code snippet:

```
echo preg_replace( '//', '8', 'lorem ipsum' );
```

which results in:

```
8l8o8r8e8m8 8i8p8s8u8m8
```

---

So Mongoose would be doing something like:

```
var_dump( preg_match( '//', 'lorem ipsum' ) );
```

which results in successfully finding "nothing"

---

In contrast `{owner: ""}` would be looking for an absence of owner data.

Comment: Late to the party, but I wanted to add that searching for `{ owner: { $regex: /^$/ } }` would give the desired result - using `^` and `$` to denote the start and end of a string, with nothing between. Without these anchors, the regex will match the search term anywhere in the string, i.e between letters as you said.

Comment: @naffarn Thanks! That is certainly valid. I am however uncertain of how it would behave in multiline data. Additionally, is there a `/m` flag? Regardless, regex seems like a heavy handed solution for finding the absence of data, hah.  Does Mongoose support `\A` or `\Z`?

Comment: You can read up on the syntax for mongo regex here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

It does support the `/m` flag, and some quick testing on my local database shows that the `\A` and `\z` anchors seem to work, although I can't find any mongo documentation on them.

Comment: @naffarn `\A` and `\Z` denote start/end of **string** respectively whereas `^` and `$` are start/end of **line**. If the regex flavor does not support these meta escapes then it's just "literal A or Z" respectively. See https://regex101.com/r/M7NPq9/1 and hover on the escapes as you switch regex flavors. If the language does not support these escapes then there are ways of emulating then with slightly convoluted regex. For example, turning on the `/s` modifier would make `^.*$` capture the entire string even if there are new lines.

Comment: @naffarn If you use just `/m` and no `/s` then `^.*$` captures each line into a separate capture. You would use these options based on whether you are doing detection, extraction, or replacement of data.

Answer (score 1):

```
{owner: {$regex: ""}}
```

this means find me nothing nothing, well there is nothing in your string which is in between letters

while this

```
{owner: ""}
```

means find me owner that's equal to this ""

i've tested your query in Robo 3T and i got the same results so i think it has to do with the regex version that mongo uses which is (PCRE-8.42)